# Convolution of two functions

Tags: convolution

for example I have somethink like that,

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}x - \frac{2}{3}  &\text{where }2 < x \leq 4, \\
\frac{-2}{3}x + \frac{10}{3} &\text{where }4 < x \leq 5. 
\end{cases}\\

g(x) &= 
\frac{-1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2} \qquad\qquad\text{where }1 \leq x \leq 3. \\
\end{align*}$$

and I would like to know how the intervals of integration look, when $f(x)$ has 2 intervals.

Comment: maybe you want to give the two functions different names (like $f_1$ and $f_2$ or $f$ and $g$)?

Comment: Maybe you want to write down what you mean by convolution.  More specifically, if $h = f*g$, how would you go about computing the value of $h(0)$?  No, not how you would go about computing $h(x)$, just $h(0)$ which is a _number._